# Where's "Copy from Active" in Blender 2.8

Tags: materials, modifiers

I'm new to the blender community. I'm using the latest 2.80 Beta release (2019-02-10) of Blender and am unable to find the "Copy from Active" option in the new interface. I'm not sure if it's in some context menu and I can't find it, or if it's missing altogether.

So the problem I'm facing right now is that say I create an array of cubes (not touching each other), apply the modifier and separate the cubes by loose parts. I then apply a physics attribute to one cube. But then I'm unable to copy those attributes to all other cubes because I cant find Copy from Active. I've found a work around of applying the physics to the object before before I separate it by loose parts. But that's just one instance of using Copy from Active option.

Can someone help me with finding the "Copy from Active" option or share some advice on a better workaround for the moment?

Answer (score 2):

You can find something similar by pressing F3 and typing : "copy rigid body settings".

Comment: Is spacebar still the default search binding in 2.8 or has it moved F3?

Comment: I don't remeber, cause i changed the keymap... I'll edit my answer, F3 is safer, thx

Comment: I need to change the keymap too lol.  Its become space oops escape F3.  Btw `<kbd>F3</kbd>` for key markdown.

Comment: By default, F3 is search, Spacebar is Playback. However, the first time one starts Blender 2.80, three options are provided for Spacebar (Search, Playback, Tool), in addition to the option to choose left click or right click select keymaps (so there isn't a single default anymore). But yea, F3 should always be safe

Answer (score 1):

You can access through the horizontal menu bar *> Object > Rigid Body*.